# Getting records from range of dates from MYSQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table below and I am trying to retrieve the number of records between specific dates.

I am getting the following error:

> 'Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in /var/www/html/dev/timeTest.php on line 18'

date column of MySQL table:

[image]

PHP:

```
 $date1 = '2018-07-01';
 $date2 = '2018-07-30';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM scanUploads WHERE dateUpload BETWEEN {$date1} AND {$date2}";
 $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
 $count = $result -> num_rows; // LINE 18
 echo 'records: '.$count;
```

Comment: use  $date1 = '2018-07-01 00:00:00';
 $date1 = '2018-07-30 23:59:59';

Comment: Is that possible that $result is null?

Comment: @DevsiI,  am not sure that I have the correct SQL syntax?  I have tried add '00:00:00' to the search dates but the error message is the same.

Comment: Is it allowed to put spaces after you want an object class? `$result -> num_rows;` should it be this? `$result->num_rows;`

Comment: you code is unsecure, try http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @kallosz this is not a `PDO` question, nor is it insecure (this example has no input at all); while I'd agree to full input sanitation & using prepared statements, which permit the substitution of `?` question marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are lacking quotation marks, which breaks the syntax.

and also the curly brackets appear rather strange to me.

there's two ways how one can formulate it, either delimiting the query-string with `'` or with `"`:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM scanUploads WHERE dateUpload BETWEEN "'.$date1.'" AND "'.$date2.'"';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scanUploads WHERE dateUpload BETWEEN \"$date1\" AND \"$date2\"";

// whenever wondering about the validity of generated SQL:
// die($sql);

// and whenever wondering about the result-set returned:
// die(print_r($result, true));
```

escaped double-quotes `\"` will always be treated literally, but only within `" "` double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date1 = '2018-07-01';
 $date1 = '2018-07-30';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM scanUploads WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(dateUpload,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '".$date1."' AND DATE_FORMAT(dateUpload,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$date2."' ";
 $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
 $count = $result -> num_rows; // LINE 18
 echo 'records: '.$count;
```